# Visual Studio does not allow to install extensions

Tags: visual-studio-code

Visual Studio will not let me install extensions, did any errors occur during the installation? I have to configure some variable? In all the videos that only click on extensions and the recommended ones come out, I do not get anything. I have the latest version of VSC installed. On the other hand, I do not see any errors in the VSC console and I can create and manage files Ok

[image: Print error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few hours ago the [marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/) was down. That caused VS Code to not show any extensions in the extension explorer. This issue was tracked [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/57851). It should be already fixed now and you should see the extensions again.

Comment: Thanks dude, now I see the extensions

Answer (score 0):

Your computer might be behind the firewall or proxy server. I had the same issue, it does not throw any error but it just times out.